Нужно разобратся с скриптом, не могу понять почему я не могу присоеденить ботов к серверу, буду благодарен любой помощи
Здравствуйте буду благодарен любой  помощи в решении проблемы
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_MlNuO7Nu3X8QuP23flLwKsFWtr6g2H5
полная ссылка на все файлы которые требуются для решения проблемы

Ранее он работал исправно но далее он перестал работать, по какой причине он перестал работать сам я не могу разобраться.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

видимо, апи вашей игрушки изменился. теперь нет домена server1444.starve.io и их вебсокет ходит по другому адресу (у меня, например, wss://frankfurt18.starve.io/frankfurtpvp1). закажите адаптацию под изменения тому же разработчику, что писал вашего бота
